Should I connect my mechanical spacer pad to GND?
Is there any advantages for connecting the mechanical spacer pads on the corners of the PCB to GND?

2D view:



3D view:



It depends on your EMC management. Multi-point grounding limits PCB/chassis parasitic capacitance.

Can you share a bit more info about the application? Generally it makes sense to connect spacers to chassis ground, though in some cases you could also connect them to the PCB ground. Not connecting them to anything at all might cause ESD problems.

Like for example, spacers used for board-to-board mounting of PCBs should probably be connected to PCB ground. Unlike spacers used to secure some PCB in a metal enclosure... depending on the nature of said enclosure. There's no general solution.

There are both advantages and disadvantages. It depends where does the spacer connect and what the PCB does. Is it a metal spacer which connects to another PCB or metal casing? What's the application?

@Justme it is just meant to be as space, to be able to do some measurements on the desk.

@Andromeda You should add that info to the question itself with an edit.


it is just meant to be as space, to be able to do some measurements on the desk. –
Andromeda

In that case definitely route it to the PCB ground. The main reason being that it helps against ESD, as there's no charge/potential build-up in the spacer itself.
But also grounded holes are very handy to have when you forgot to add that ground connection for your oscilloscope probe to the layout (again!).
